# How to implement a template in Magento

Tags: php, templates, magento

I am stuck in a very difficult condition. I have made some small projects in PHP/MySQL like a blog in which a user can log in make some posts, and categories with the option of deleting and editing posts. While a visitor can browse the blog by posts and categories, can also post comments. Similarly I have also made a news admin panel for a news application where news can submit news and categories with pictures and can edit or delete any news.

All this work was done by using simple PHP without OOP, though I know how OOP works have all the basic concepts. Some days back I got a job of PHP trainee and the first thing which I was told to do is to implement the template of Magento.

Well I have only heard the name of magento before and while exploring it I found it is a very big ecommerce application developed under Zend Framework. I explored it well and figured out how themes works in websites, stores and store views but I don't think I am still in the position to customize Magento

Any Advice or Suggestion except I should leave the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is NOT a difficult situation. It's actually, a great opportunity come your way. So, relax.

You have good English, plus PHP skills to start off with, that's a great beginning. And Magento, like any of the customizable Open Source technologies, is designed to be easy to customize.

Guess your approach would be:

1. [User Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento-user-guide-book)  -- Read all that you need to know, its not much, and its fun.
2. Take a good example Magento site and peek into its internals -- See how it's done.

We all learn in our own individual quirky ways, but the above should be helpful to anyone.

And, no, you need NOT leave the job. All the Best!